# I am unable to make a foreign key in the table. An error message keeps appearing

Tags: mysql

[image of the code and error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCbZU.png)

```
CREATE TABLE Ticket(
    -> Ticket_No INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    -> BusID INT,
    -> Registration_No INT,
    -> Seat_No INT NOT NULL,
    -> FOREIGN KEY BusID REFERENCES Bus(BusID),
    -> FOREIGN KEY Registration_No REFERENCES Passenger(Registration_No));
```

Error message:

> ```
> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax;
> check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'REFERENCES Bus(BusID),
> FOREIGN KEY Registration_No REFERENCES Passenger(Registra' at line 6
> ```

I am trying to add foreign keys to this table but this error message keeps appearing. The referenced table and column name is correct. I have also tried changing the column name. Please help.

Comment: Please don't attach images here. Paste it as code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put parenthesis around the referencing column(s).

```
...
FOREIGN KEY (BusID) REFERENCES Bus(BusID),
...
```

And analog for the other one.